# How could I split the text of the x axis labels?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I'm doing a bar graph with pgfplots. The labels of x axis are looking disproportionate and I don't know how to fix it. Is there anyway to make them better? Furthermore, It could be better if the strings are aligned like the picture.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar=-1cm,
    xtick = {Espacio Geográfico,Democracia y Desarrollo,Chile y América en perspectiva histórica,El mundo en perspectiva histórica},
    %axis x line*=bottom,
    %axis y line*=left,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    height=10 cm, width= 10 cm,
    bar width=1 cm,
    ylabel={\% de Aprobación},
    %xlabel = {Eje Temático},
    symbolic x coords={Espacio Geográfico,Democracia y Desarrollo,Chile y América en perspectiva histórica,El mundo en perspectiva histórica},
    x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=left},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical}          
    ]
    \addplot[black,fill=espacio] coordinates {(Espacio Geográfico,67)};
    \addplot[black,fill=democracia] coordinates {(Democracia y Desarrollo, 64)};
    \addplot[black,fill=chile] coordinates {(Chile y América en perspectiva histórica,44)};
    \addplot[black,fill=mundo] coordinates {(El mundo en perspectiva histórica,57)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now It looks like this

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with "disproportionate"? And to your second question: You mean that the xticklabels should all start at the red line and if necessary wrapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could produce was this, It is a bit fragile since some extra padding was needed for the first shorter entry.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[title  = Example,
    height=10 cm, width= 10 cm,
    ybar=-1cm, ylabel={\% de Aprobación},
    ymin=0, ymax=100, ytick distance=10, axis y line = left,
    xmin=1, xmax=4, xtick distance=1, bar width=1.5 cm, axis x line = bottom,xtick=\empty,enlarge x limits=0.2,
    axis background/.style={fill=yellow!10},{fill=red},
    x tick label style={major tick length=0},
    extra x tick style={major tick length=0,tick label style={anchor=east,align=left,text width=2cm,rotate=45}},
    extra x ticks={1.2,2.2,3.2,4.2},
    extra x tick labels={
    Espacio ~~Geográfico,Democracia y Desarrollo,Chile y América en perspectiva histórica,El mundo en perspectiva histórica},
   nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={vertical},
    xticklabel shift={0.5cm}
]
\addplot+ [olive] coordinates {%
(1,67) (2,64) (3,44) (4,57) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### **Updated per comments**

If you want to move the title to under the x axis try first line

```
\begin{axis}[title = Eje Temático, title style={at={(0.5,-0.1)}},
```

However I think the correct way to label x is

```
\begin{axis}[xlabel=Eje Temático,every axis x label/.style={at={(0.5,-0.04)}},
```

Alternatively to emulate captioning you could try

```
\begin{axis}[xlabel=Fig1: Eje Temático,
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks nice.